# I would like to re-pack MKV files while keeping ALL subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, nvidia

I have been using MakeMKV to rip DVDs to my hard drive. This program works OK, but produces very inefficient files. Resulting video files from Blu-Rays are typically 35GB or more. I would like to use ffmpeg to re-pack these files, mkv to mkv, while keeping all the subtitles. I have a good video card (nvidia RTV 2060), so I would like to do it with hardware encoding, since these are feature-length movies.

Something like this works:

ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -i in.mkv -vcodec h264_nvenc out.mkv

But I lose the subtitles.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

## Add `-map 0`

- Default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior **only selects one stream per stream type**. So not all of your subtitles are being copied.
- The `-map` output option disables this behavior and allows you to manually select what streams you want. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more info.
- `-map 0` selects **all** streams (from input #0, the only input in your case).

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -i in.mkv -map 0 -codec:v h264_nvenc -codec:a copy -codec:s copy out.mkv
```

`-codec:a copy -codec:s copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode for the audio and subtitles so it will not re-encode the audio and subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

You really should checkout [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/), they even offer a [HandBrakeCLI](https://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php). It's a very user friendly way of transcoding/muxing media into a preferred format, bitrate, or container.

Failing handbrake, and if you are okay with MP4 containers, you can embed subtitles inside of an mp4 container using:

`ffmpeg -i %1 -i %2 -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy %3`
Saved as a addsubs.bat, you would:
`addsubs source.mkv subs.srt destination.mp4`